# how to redict monitoring results from stdin to vim?

Tags: vim, monitoring, tail

There is a stdin screen, being fed by `tail -f log_file`. And I want to view the monitoring result in a edit like `vim`, so that the monitored data can be searched at the same time. Is it possible to do this?

PS: I have tried `tail -f log_file | vim -`, which does not work, 'cause `vim` will not continuously monitor `stdin`.

Answer (score 2):

This may only indirectly answer your question, but if you only worry about *searching*, why not simply pipe it into `less` instead of `vim`? You can find in less just the same (with `/`).

Comment: `less` has a lot of Vi-like keybindings. I assumed for years that it was quite dumb but reading `$ man less` was eye-opening. `&pattern` is great, so is the ability to create marks.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the file in Vim (`gvim -R log_file`) and then use a map like this to make reloading quick:

```
nnoremap <S-space> :e<CR>
```